# SQL Job Fails on Python call in Powershell Script

Tags: python, sql-server, powershell

I have a powershell script that I'd like to run as a SQL Agent Job.

It contains 3 lines:

Invoke-SqlCmd...
Copy-Item...
python...

The first 2 lines work flawlessly, however the job fails on the third line in which I call some python.

The powershell script works fine when run manually from the powershell ISE. I assume, and this appears to be the case from some googling that the SQL Agent doesn't like or can't run python on its own, however I would have assumed that since its all part of a powershell script I would get around that problem.

The SQL job error is:

```
Executed as user: DOMAIN\SQL_ReportServer. A job step received an error at line 3 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'python StripQuotes.py "E:\DW_Exports\Pearsonvue\CDD.txt"'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.
```

Is there anyway to get this process working?

Comment: Is it possible that the SQL Agent runs on another machine and there is no python installed or it isn't in the PATH variable of that system?

Comment: @NtFreX Not the problem in this case I don't believe. We have a simple setup with only a single machine that houses our SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

`python` is not visible in the PATH for the context of the SQL Server Agent or powershell proxy account. Try invoking python using the fully qualified pathname (e.g. `C:\Python37\python.exe`). You may encounter further errors which you should then debug as new and separate problems.